# How to display one site or page, but show different URL using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to display `aaa.com/test.php`, but show `bbb.com` in the browser's URL field. According to [this site](https://support.mivamerchant.com/supportsuite/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/1113/88/point-alias-domains-to-a-specific-page-on-the-main-website), I should use the following in the `.htaccess` file on `aaa.com`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} bbbs.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test.php [R=301,L]
```

However, when I visit `aaa.com/test.php` there is no re-direct to follow. It still shows `aaa.com/test.php`.

Comment: Do you own both domains? Do they point to the same IP?

Comment: I own both domains, but both do not point to the same IP.. even though they are on the same server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was as simple as using a RewriteRule with the [[P] proxy flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p), which causes the request to be handled by [`mod_proxy`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://destinationdomain.com/$1 [P]
```